# LogisticRegression scikit learn covariate (column) order matters on training

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

For some reason the order of the covariates seems to matter with a [`LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) classifier in scikit-learn, which seems odd to me. I have 9 covariates and a binary output, and when I change the order of the columns and call `fit()` and then call `predict_proba()` the output is different. Toy example below

```
logit_model = LogisticRegression(C=1e9, tol=1e-15)
```

The following

```
logit_model.fit(df['column_2','column_1'],df['target'])
logit_model.predict_proba(df['column_2','column_1'])

array([[ 0.27387109,  0.72612891] ..])
```

Gives a different result to:

```
logit_model.fit(df['column_1','column_2'],df['target'])
logit_model.predict_proba(df['column_1','column_2'])

array([[ 0.26117794,  0.73882206], ..])
```

This seems surprising to me but maybe thats just my lack of knowledge about the internals of the algorithm and the fit method.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Here is the full code and data

data: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gjt-personal/test_model.csv

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_csv('test_model.csv',index_col=False)

columns1 =['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6','col_7','col_8','col_9']
columns2 =['col_2','col_1','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6','col_7','col_8','col_9']

logit_model = LogisticRegression(C=1e9, tol=1e-15)

logit_model.fit(df[columns1],df['target'])
logit_model.predict_proba(df[columns1])

logit_model.fit(df[columns2],df['target'])
logit_model.predict_proba(df[columns2])
```

Turns out its something to do with `tol=1e-15` because this gives a different result.

```
LogisticRegression(C=1e9, tol=1e-15)
```

But this gives the same result.

```
LogisticRegression(C=1e9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding sample data.

Taking a deeper look at your data it is clearly not standardized. If you were to apply a [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to the dataset and try fitting again you will find that the prediction discrepancy disappears.

While this result is at least consistent it is still troubling that it raises a `LineSearchWarning` and `ConvergenceWarning`. To that I would say you do have an exceedingly low tolerance here at `1e-15`. Given the very high regularization penalty ratio (`1e9`) you have applied, lowering `tol` to the default `1e-4` will really have no impact whatsoever. This allows the model to properly converge and still produces the same outcome (in a much faster run time).

My full process looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

ss = StandardScaler()
cols1 = np.arange(9)
cols2 = np.array([1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
X = ss.fit_transform(df.drop('target', axis=1))

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg', tol=1e-4, C=1e9)
lr.fit(X[:, cols1], df['target'])
preds_1 = lr.predict_proba(X[:, cols1])

lr.fit(X[:, cols2], df['target'])
preds_2 = lr.predict_proba(X[:, cols2])

preds_1 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [  1.00000000e+00,   9.09277801e-31],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   3.52079327e-35],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   5.99607407e-30]])

preds_2
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [  1.00000000e+00,   9.09277801e-31],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   3.52079327e-35],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   5.99607407e-30]])
```

The assertion `preds_1 == preds_2` will fail, but the difference is on the order of 1e-40 + for each value, which I would say is well beyond any plausible level of significance.

Comment: Grr yeh thats what I was thinking but in the docs it says: "Used when solver == ‘sag’ or ‘liblinear’." which is why I used `newton-cg` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: hmm if I rerun with `logit_model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)` the outputs are equal, but if I run, `LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, C=1e9,tol=1e-15, solver='newton-cg',random_state=0)` its still different, even running `LogisticRegression()` its the same

Comment: Well in that case you aren't using newton-cg anymore so that makes sense

Comment: So its something to do with the `tol` attribute. `LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, C=1e9,tol=1e-15)` is different but `LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, C=1e9)` is the same, know why that would be?

Comment: ah "Notes:
The underlying C implementation uses a random number generator to select features when fitting the model. It is thus not uncommon, to have slightly different results for the same input data. If that happens, try with a smaller tol parameter."

Comment: But when I adjust that number if gives very different outputs, which is concerning in its own right... `[ 0.43773937,  0.56226063]` vs `[ 0.26284889,  0.73715111]` seems very drastic going from `tol=1e-6` to `tol=1e-4`. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

This is measuring the same thing in both code samples.

When we feed a `DataFrame` to a classifier in sklearn, it trains on each individual row of the data frame (each row corresponds to one observation)

So the order of the rows doesn't matter, since the output you're getting is the probability that the particular row corresponds to each of the possible classes.

For example:

An output of `array([[ 0.26117794,  0.73882206], ..])` means that the row that we fed to the classifier has a ~26% chance of being in class 0 and a ~74% chance of being in class 1. This measurement isn't saying anything about the individual columns. Just the row as a whole.

Let me know if that helps and if I can clarify my answer at all.

Comment: So my question is not about the interpretation of the output or it being different for different rows, its about it being different for the the same row when the order of the columns is different on `fit`

Comment: Based on the code, the output is the exact same. Can you provide an example where the output is different for the same row of data?

Comment: What do you mean the output is the exact same? Its different. Do you mean it should be the exact same?

Comment: Oh jesus I completely missed that. I feel very stupid.

Comment: The actual answer is that logistic regression uses gradient descent to reach its final form, which means there's some randomness involved. Refitting the model will always change the predictions, no matter what order the rows are in.
You can test this by setting a random seed in your train_test_split()